# Things to visit in UK other than world famous spots in UK like London Eye and all

Tags: uk, international-travel, europe, london

I am planning to Visit UK at the end of Nov 2019 for 15 days, considering weather what are all the spots I can visit other than London Eye. Westminster Abbey, tower bridge, museum etc.
In and around London or any other part of UK (3-4 hrs drive from London).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately this site isn't particularly well-suited for this sort of question, as there is no one right/best answer; it's primarily based on opinion and also very broad. If you have some more specific and definitively answerable questions about your trip those would do well here, but I'd recommend you check sites designed to give trip recommendations, or ask friends who have visited if you know people who have. Good luck! As an aside, I'd also recommend considering options other than driving; domestic trains are generally a better option for getting places from London.

Comment: 4 hours drive from London covers half of England... that's a LOT of tourist attractions. You don't even give any indication of what you like (museums, buildings, geology, steam railways, motorsports...?). How is anyone supposed to narrow it down enough to answer?

Comment: We don't know what the weather will be like at the end of November – our climate is fickle, with local variations. So you need to come prepared for different weather and be flexible in your plans - some indoor things, some outdoors, some involving trips out of London, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are literally thousands of things you can do in & around London, and all tastes & interests are catered for. For instance:

- Cabinet War Rooms
- Transport Museum
- Greenwich Naval museum, Observatory & Cutty Sark
- Open-top bus tours
- West end shows
- Imperial War Museum
- Football matches
- Rugby matches
- Boat trips on the Thames
- Shopping!
- Loads of good restaurants
- Lots of lively areas (Brick Lane, Camden etc)

I haven't even scratched the surface with this list.

Comment: Stonehenge  is doable